# mounting sdb on /mnt using docker and openfoam

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, openfoam

I recently found the post entitled "How to mount volumes in docker release of openFOAM" post on this site on October 2016. That post asks about automatically
mounting an already mounted (under bash or csh) volume through the Docker version of openfoam. Hopefully, this is explained below.

I have the situation that under `csh`, the output from `lsblk` is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk /mnt/hdd
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0 103.9G  0 part /
```

Then I run the script `startOpenFOAM+`, which is the following Bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script will
#   i) Start  OpenFOAM+ container with name 'of_v1612_plus'
#  in the  the shell-terminal.
#  User also need to run xhost+ from other terminal
#  Note: Docker daemon should be running before launching script
#  PostProcessing: User can launch paraview/paraFoam from terminal
#  to postprocess the results
#  Note: user can launch script in different  shell to have OpenFOAM
#  working environment in different terminal
xhost +local:of_v1612_plus
docker start  of_v1612_plus
docker exec -it of_v1612_plus /bin/bash -rcfile /opt/OpenFOAM/setImage_v1612+
```

I am dumped into a Bash shell and the output from `lsblk` is now:

```
bash-4.1$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
|-sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
|-sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
`-sda1   8:1    0 103.9G  0 part /etc/sudoers.d
```

I guess the answer to the problem is to add the line `docker run -v ....` into the `startOpenFOAM+` shell script. However, I am not sure what to replace the dots with and where to place the command.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need this:

```
docker run -v /mnt/hdd:/mnt/hdd .....
```

But you didn't showed where you `docker run`, if you find it, then add that `-v`.

Important: you will not see a mount point with `lsblk` inside container regarding `sdb`, because docker mount a directory, not a device. You just will see contents in /mnt/hdd